# Run Python Code Via PHP show different result than running it via Terminal

Tags: php, python, linux, bash, python-2.7

## Python

I have a python code

```
import paramiko
import time
import sys
import os
import pdb



ip = "1.1.1.1"
un = "root"
pw = "123"
key_filename='/path/to/id_rsa'

def ssh_con (ip, un, pw):
    global ssh
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, username=un, password=pw, key_filename=key_filename)

def cmd_io (command):
    global ssh_cmd
    ssh_cmd.send("%s \n" %command)
    time.sleep(1)
    output = ssh_cmd.recv(10000).decode("utf-8")
    print (output)

ssh_con(ip,un,pw)
ssh_cmd = ssh.invoke_shell()
cmd_io("clientsim cli")
time.sleep(2)
cmd_io("stop subscriber-group dth-sub stop-traffic udp")
time.sleep(1)
cmd_io("stop subscriber-group dth-sub")
time.sleep(1)
cmd_io("q")
cmd_io("exit")
```

---

## PHP

I'm trying to run it via PHP

I've tried

```
$command = "python ".public_path().'/python/start_clientsim.py 2>&1';
$result = shell_exec($command);
```

I kept getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):↵  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/site/portal/public/python/stop_clientsim.py", line 32, in ↵    cmd_io("clientsim cli")↵  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/site/portal/public/python/stop_clientsim.py", line 28, in cmd_io↵    print (output)↵UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 360-362: ordinal not in range(128)↵

But if I run

```
python /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/site/portal/public/python/stop_clientsim.py 2>&1
```

[image]

on my Terminal directly, it works perfectly fine.

What did I do wrong here ?

How would one go about and debug this further ?

Comment: Usually you would `print(output.encode('utf-8'))`...

Comment: Have you tried `print (output.decode('utf-8'))` ?

Comment: I would try to prepend something like `LC_ALL=C` or `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` (followed by a space) to the `python` `$command`

Comment: regarding `LC_ALL=...`, please note there must be no spaces around the `=`

Comment: @Robert :  I thought I did that already in my cmd_io function. `output = ssh_cmd.recv(10000).decode("utf-8")`

Comment: No luck with `LC_ALL`? The rationale is that locale settings, which include encoding, could be different between your shell and the shell that's invoked by `shell_exec()`.

Comment: I tried `python /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/benu/ssc-portal/public/python/start_clientsim.py LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` It SSH into my VM, then it exiting back out right away.

Comment: You may see the result here = https://www.flickr.com/photos/149890841@N04/

Comment: Try adding `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` at the top of the python file

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo but you ran different commands. The PHP script runs `start_clientsim.py` and you ran `stop_clientsim.py` on CLI.